# Write unit test for a method in a component in Vue with Jest

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm starting with unit testing with Jest Vue. I want to test an existing method in a Vue component, I write a test but it does not pass. And I do not have any idea how to mock and call that method in test.

How can I write a good unit test, to pass the functionality of 'goPage()' method?

My method is:

```
goPage(id, name, categoryId) {
   this.headerSearchInput = name
   this.$router.push({
      path: '/categories/' + categoryId + '/courses/' + id,
      query: { query: this.headerSearchInput },
   })
}
```

My test is:

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HeaderSearch from '../../components/header/HeaderSearch.vue'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(VueRouter)
const router = new VueRouter()

describe('Header search component', () => {
   const mockRoute = {
      path: '/categories/' + 2 + '/courses/' + 4,
      query: {
        query: searchedText,
      },
   }
   const mockRouter = {
      push: jest.fn(),
   }
   const wrapper = shallowMount(HeaderSearch, {
      router,
      localVue,
      stubs: {
        NuxtLink: true,
      },
      global: {
        mocks: {
          $route: mockRoute,
          $router: mockRouter,
        },
      },
   })
   test('redirect to course page, goPage', async () => {
      const courseId = 4
      const courseTitle = 'Inbound Marketing'
      const categoryId = 2

      const mockedFunction = jest.fn()
      wrapper.vm.goPage(courseId, courseTitle, categoryId)
      await wrapper.setData({
        headerSearchInput: courseTitle,
      })
      const expectedRouter = {
        path: '/categories/3/courses/4',
        query: { query: wrapper.vm.headerSearchInput },
      }
      expect(mockedFunction).toBeCalledWith(courseId, courseTitle, categoryId)
      expect(wrapper.vm.$router.path).toEqual(expectedRouter.path)
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When you test routing you should use only mocking without installing `VueRouter` on your `local Vue` instance. As official [documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#using-with-vue-router) says:

> Installing Vue Router on a localVue also adds $route and $router as read-only properties to a localVue. This means you can not use the mocks option to overwrite $route and $router when mounting a component using a localVue with Vue Router installed.

So you need to get reed of `localVue` in `shallowMount` call and leave only `$router` mocking:

Then in test you just call your `goPage` method and check that `$router.push()` was called with certain argument. **Without checking that `$route.path` has been changed leaving this to end-to-end tests.**

```
let wrapper
describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld, {
      global: { mocks: { $router: { push: jest.fn() } } }
    })
  })

  test('redirect to course page, goPage', async () => {
    const courseId = 4
    const courseTitle = 'Inbound Marketing'
    const categoryId = 2
    const expectedRouter = {
      path: '/categories/' + categoryId + '/courses/' + courseId,
      query: { query: 'Inbound Marketing' }
    }
    wrapper.vm.goPage(courseId, courseTitle, categoryId)
    expect(wrapper.vm.$router.push).toBeCalledWith(expectedRouter)
  })
})
```

Comment: I wrote the test like what you said, but it throws `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` error. How can I fix that?  @Eduardo

Comment: Please, provide the code of your test with wrapper instantiation.

Comment: The code is long , so I write it in 2 comments.

`const wrapper = shallowMount(HeaderSearch, {
    stubs: {
      NuxtLink: true,
    },
    global: {
      mocks: {
        $router: {
           push: jest.fn(),
        },
      },
    },
  })`

Comment: `test('redirect to course page, goPage', async () => {
    const courseId = 4
    const courseTitle = 'Inbound Marketing'
    const categoryId = 2
    const expectedRouter = {
      path: '/categories/' + categoryId + '/courses/' + courseId,
      query: { query: wrapper.vm.headerSearchInput },
    }

    wrapper.vm.goPage(courseId, courseTitle, categoryId)
    await wrapper.setData({
      headerSearchInput: courseTitle,
    })
    expect(wrapper.vm.$router.push).toBeCalledWith(expectedRouter)
  })`

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it, please.

Comment: Unfortunately I got same error!
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

    goPage(courseId, courseTitle, categoryId) {
       this.headerSearchInput = courseTitle
   >  this.$router.push({
          path: '/categories/' + categoryId + '/courses/' + courseId,
          query: { query: this.headerSearchInput },
     })`

Comment: I think you have a typo somewhere, I checked the code in my IDE, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved My problem like below:

```
let wrapper
describe('HeaderSearch', () => {
   const $route = {
     path: '/categories/2/courses/4',
   }
   const $router = {
     push: jest.fn(),
   }
   beforeEach(() => {
   wrapper = shallowMount(HeaderSearch, {
      mocks: {
        $route,
        $router,
      },
  })
})

test('go to each course page', () => {
  const courseId = 4
  const categoryId = 2
  const courseTitle = 'Inbound Marketing'

  wrapper.vm.goPage(courseId, courseTitle, categoryId)
  const expectedRouter = {
    path: '/categories/' + categoryId + '/courses/' + courseId,
    query: { query: courseTitle },
  }
  expect(wrapper.vm.$router.push).toBeCalledWith(expectedRouter)
  })
})
```